# Drawing to canvas from another class in Cinder

Tags: oop, opengl, cinder

Is there a way I can draw using libcinder without having to put all my code on the draw() method of the main class. I'm working on a big app and it's not convenient in any way to have everything stuffed in one file.

This is an example of what the idea would be:

```
class MyApp : public AppBasic {
  public:
    void setup ();
    void update ();
    void draw ();
  private:
    vector<MyObject> myObjects;
};

MyApp::draw () {
  for (int i = 0; i < myObjects.size(); ++i) {
    myObjects[i].render ();
  }
}

CINDER_APP_BASIC (MyApp, RendererGL)

/* ------------------ */

class MyObject {

  public:
    void render ();

};

void MyObject::render () {
  Rectf rect (0, 0, 20, 20);
  gl::drawSolidRoundedRect(rect, 15.0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way. Several ways, actually.

1. Create a class with at least the following methods: `void setup()`, `void update()` and `void draw()`. In the main application you can then create instances of this class, store them in a member variable or `std::vector`. Then simply call the methods from the main application's `setup`, `update` and `draw` methods respectively.
2. Use Cinder's event system to connect to its `update` and `draw` events. See the ListenerBasic sample: https://github.com/cinder/Cinder/tree/master/samples/ListenerBasic . For a list of all available events, see: https://github.com/cinder/Cinder/blob/master/include/cinder/app/Window.h .
3. Write or use a scene graph system which handles drawing all your objects. It will call each of your object's `draw()` method in the correct order, can put objects on top of other objects, can detect which object is under the cursor, etc. A well-known scene graph is http://www.openscenegraph.org/ , but it is not compatible with Cinder. A very basic scene graph can be found in one of my samples: https://github.com/paulhoux/Cinder-Samples/tree/master/SimpleSceneGraph

-Paul